# Which browser returns the correct result for getBoundingClientRect of an SVG element?

Tags: css, svg, standards

This SVG contains a rect which overflows the SVG element:

```
<svg id='svg' width='10' height='10'>
  <rect x='-10' y='-10' width='30' height='30'/>
</svg>
```

Chrome 28 and Opera 12 return a `getBoundingClientRect()` for the SVG element with a width and height of 10. Firefox 23 reports a width and height of 30. Which is correct?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnRWS/)

The relevant spec is [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods), which delegates to the SVG spec if the SVG element does not "have an associated CSS layout box". I haven't found a definition of "having an associated CSS layout box", but the correct result would seem to hinge on this definition, as [`getBBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) returns a 30x30 rect in all browsers.

Comment: is this the notorious SVG bounding box bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Firefox bug was fixed in Firefox 33. See [bug 530985](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530985) for details.